# How can I access a shared mailbox through Graph explorer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

My outlook account at work is a member of a group called GraphTest which has email address GraphTest@companyname.net.

I'm trying to use the [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to access mail in that group's inbox.

When I run the query https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/graphtest@companyname.net/messages I get the error message

> Group Shard is used in non-Groups URI.

When I replace graphtest@companyname.net with my own email it works. Also I've consented to the permissions Mail.Read and Mail.Read.Shared.

What does this error message mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/graphtest@companyname.net/messages

Firstly the above API call which you used is invalid because you are giving a group email id to get it from user like `/users/graphtest@companyname.net/messages` which is invalid.

Even there is no mention in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) that we can use something like `/groups/graphtest@companyname.net/messages`.

You can get some details from [List Conversations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-conversations?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) using something like this.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group_id_only}/conversations`